# AWS and Fortigate NGFW yielding IGW_REJECTS_SPOOFED_TRAFFIC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, fortigate

I've got a Fortigate NGFW sitting in my AWS that my company uses for SSL-VPN & IPSEC access to clients. We've recently started hosting our own EC2 servers behind the Fortigate.
They're able to reach through the VPNs just fine but aren't able to hit the wider internet despite all of the correct policies being in place on the Fortigate.

When I run the AWS Reachability Analyzer I get the following error IGW_REJECTS_SPOOFED_TRAFFIC. I've done a fair amount of googling on the issue. My Security Groups look fine, the Fortigate is performing NAT on traffic leaving the box. My AWS routing table has a default route pointed at the Internet Gateway and I've disabled Source/Destination check on the Fortigate.
I'm pretty stumped anyone got any ideas?

Comment: "Gateways reject traffic from network interfaces if the source IP address is not a public IP address associated with the network interface." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/explanation-codes.html sounds like the outgoing IP address on packets coming out of the fortigate don't match public IP of fortigate instance.

Comment: The server is sitting in a private aws subnet and I've got NAT enabled on the fortigate internet access policy.

Comment: @A-Big-Moose When you analyze network connectivity from NGFW to the IGW, after you get the first result try hitting the `analyze` button at the top of the page and require the analysis to show you the result corresponding to the path through the NAT Gateway. You can do that using the ARN of the NAT Gateway. That should give you a more precise result than the one you have seen.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck have you disabled this for the fortigate instance?